# Multidimensional ragged array of type that extends generic trait

Tags: arrays, scala, multidimensional-array, initializer-list

Let's say I have a trait, `Foo` and this trait takes a generic type `Bar` so that the definition for Foo would look exactly like

```
trait Foo[C <: Bar] {
    def updateState(state : C) : C;
}
```

, and I have several classes `action1`, `action2`, `action3` ... `action9` that extend `Foo`.

Now, let's say I want to explicitly initialize a 2d array of these actions.

I've tried

```
Array[Foo[Bar]](
Array(new action1, new action2),
Array(new action2, new action3)...
) 
Array[Foo[Bar]](
Array[Foo[Bar]](new action1, new action2),
Array[Foo[Bar]](new action2, new action3)...
)
```

and most of the permutations of adding the `[Foo[Bar]]` with bar `[Foo]` without bar, making  the main array `Array[Array[Foo[Bar]]]` etc.

I've found a solution to the problem by using

```
Array.ofDim[Foo[Bar]](size1, size2, size3)
```

and manually initializing each dimension but I'd like to know if there is some way to explicitly initialize a 2d array of a type that implements a generic trait...yes, I know there are about 3 use cases for doing this (not really but it's not very common) so an answer like "Why are you doing this?" or "There are better ways of bla bla bla" won't be too impacting on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can define relation between index of item and instance of class, than use:

```
tabulate[T](n1: Int, n2: Int)(f: (Int, Int) ⇒ T)
```

Example:

```
Array.tabulate(5, 5) {
  case (i, j) => new action(i, j)
}
```

**Update:**

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)    
trait Bar
class Foo[C <: Bar]

Array.tabulate(5, 5) {
  case (i, j) => new Foo[Bar]()
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined trait Bar
defined class Foo
res1: Array[Array[Foo[Bar]]] = Array(Array(Foo@5e1c4451, Foo@11c9521c, Foo@382db563, Foo@40df9365, Foo@1645ed29), Array(Foo@48d52a2b, Foo@22c39268, Foo@55c0fbac, Foo@70cb052f, Foo@20c18a83), Array(Foo@26caf42, Foo@2d66174c, Foo@98395dd, Foo@1de3e50c, Foo@5cd28628), Array(Foo@165dbb4, Foo@463b0723, Foo@4d51aeda, Foo@2dae91de, Foo@1fea9d40), Array(Foo@63f9e51e, Foo@2b3147d9, Foo@30640db6, Foo@78c0408b, Foo@15cda39c))
```

Comment: Could you make a 2 dimensional ragged array of `[Foo[Bar]]` using this? I don't see how your explain or the code implies that you can.